# Обработка строки даты

Tags: c++, строки

Пользователь вводит дату в формате `01/02/17`, нужно сохранить дату в трёх переменных `int` соответственно-`day`,`month`,`year`. Я разбивал строку с датой на 3 подстроки и переводил в каждую в `int`. Мне кажется-не самый лучший способ. Есть ли како-то более удачное решение для такой обработки?

Comment: Если Вы имеете дело с managed с++, то класс DateTime решит все Ваши проблемы

Comment: можете заюзать boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_tutorial но, думаю в вашем случае, то что вы делаете, это лучший вариант )

Comment: Вас имеющийся способ (кстати, где он?) чем-то не устраивает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно и удобно регэкспами:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::vector<int> GetDigitDate(const std::string Date) {
  std::regex Rx("^(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{2}|\\d{4})$");
  std::smatch Match;
  if(!(std::regex_match(Date, Match, Rx) && (Match.size()==4))) 
    throw std::runtime_error("");
  return {std::stoi(Match[1]),std::stoi(Match[2]),std::stoi(Match[3])};
}

int main() { 
  try {
    std::vector<int> T = GetDigitDate("1/07/2011");
    for(const auto &i:T) std::cout << i << std::endl; 
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Что-то не так!" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Естественно, при желании, можно дополнить проверку корректности дней, месяцев и годов. В коде - простейшая проверка просто на числа.

**ADD:**

Если не нравится возврат вектора, в качестве результата, небольшая модификация кода, но для C++1z

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::tuple<int,int,int> GetDigitDate(const std::string Date) {
  std::regex Rx("^(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{2}|\\d{4})$");
  std::smatch Match;
  if(!(std::regex_match(Date, Match, Rx) && (Match.size()==4))) 
    throw std::runtime_error("");
  return {std::stoi(Match[1]),std::stoi(Match[2]),std::stoi(Match[3])};
}

int main() { 
  try {
    auto [d,m,y] = GetDigitDate("1/07/2011");
    std::cout << "d: " << d << " m: " << m << " y: " << y << std::endl; 
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Что-то не так!" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: а оно исходный авторский запрос (01/02/17) не понимает. Возвращать результат в векторе? ужас. Можно же сделать класс, который нормально возвратить.

О количестве оверхеда в этом коде я просто молчу. Решение @Harry было на порядок лучше.

Comment: Рекэксп поправил, это же 5 сек - зачем на этом заострять внимание. Если есть вектор и нет класса, и вектор решает в полной мере  - лучче возвратить вектор, а не писать класс. Читайте Бритву Оккама. Об оверхеде можно говорить на нагруженных вычислениях, там это существенно. А тут не понятно - возможно и UI. Но я не настаиваю на решении, на вкус и цвет - фломастеры разные.

Comment: бритва Оккама здесь идет лесом. Вектор возвращает три значения. Как рядовому пользователю класса узнать, что там. Вот американцы решат, что там в начале месяц. И будут правы.

А регулярка стала ещё сложнее:)

Comment: Рядовому пользователю читать доку надо, на не разгадывать код.

Comment: А в Вашем случае ее нет. Так что нет чего читать. Более того, с первого взгляда даже не понятно, что оно возвращает.

Comment: Просто заминусуйте мой ответ, и закончим.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, который использует [QDate::fromString() из Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1):

```
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* date_string = (argc == 2) ? argv[argc-1] : "01/02/17";
  QDate d = QDate::fromString(date_string, "dd/MM/yy");
  d = d.addYears(100); // 19yy -> 20yy

  int year, month, day;
  d.getDate(&year, &month, &day);
  qDebug() << year << month << day;
  return !year; // if the year is zero; the date is invalid
}
```

Код автоматически проверяет, что введённая дата является корректной (кол-во дней в месяце, високосные годы, итд). Пример:

```
$ ./parse-date 5/10/14
2014 10 5
```

Двузначный год интерпретируется всегда как 19yy, поэтому `00` (2000) не распознаётся как високосный год (важно для `2000-02-29`).

Answer (score 0):

А почему не воспользоваться просто `scanf`? Эта функция и в C++ работает:

```
int day, month, year;
if (sscanf("01/02/17","%d/%d/%d",&month,&day,&year) == 3)
{
    printf("Date is %02d.%02d.%d\n",day,month,year+2000);
}
```

Comment: @AnT Ой... Извините, задумался!... :(